# How can I escape the parsed data from an XHR function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My question is essentially that I am trying to make a universal Ajax function solely for retrieving information which will be parsed and then automatically stored as the value of whatever called it. In this specific case it is a giant dictionary word-list for a hangman game I am making. How can I escape the Array that is created by `ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n")` into whatever calls it. In my case it will be `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist`

**My end goal is to be able to use `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist[i]` and have it return the value of whatever string is stored at that place in the Array.**

Before you freak out this isn't all of my code the XHR request function is called through `ALAMI.XHR();` as written below but I didn't include it in this code because I felt it was unnecessary.

```
ALAMI.XHR.Get = function(URL){
  "use strict";
  var ajaxRequest = ALAMI.XHR();
  var ajaxResponse;

  ajaxRequest.open("GET", URL, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
      ajaxResponse = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n");
      var extensionLocation = URL.lastIndexOf('.');
      console.log(URL.substr(extensionLocation) + " file ...... " + ajaxResponse.length + " lines.");
    }
  }
  return ajaxResponse;
}

ALAMI.Hangman = ALAMI.Hangman || {};

ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist = ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt');

//I want ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist to be equal to the Array of ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n")
```

**My end goal is to be able to use `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist[i]` and have it return the value of whatever string is stored at that place in the Array.**

Also I'm trying to make my ajax function a universal method that I can use an infinite number of times. for example:

```
 ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist1 = ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt');
 ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist2 = ALAMI.XHR.Get('dictionary2.txt');
```

The end goal is:

If in the global space I write `console.log(ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist[0]);` it currently shows up as undefined, however, what I want is for the array to have been stored in `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist` so that when I do that it will ouput the first value of the array.

`console.log(ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist[0]); //Should output Apple`

Comment: Many points: (1) What's ALAMI? (2) `fulldictiornay.txt` does not look like a valid URL to me (3) Did you know that  `onreadystatechange` function is executing in a different thread and that any value in onreadystatechange's `ajaxResponse` will be unavailable in the main thread's `return ajaxaResponse` will never work?

Comment: ALAMI is my personal namespace for everything I create in javascript (as opposed to YAHOO or something). and fulldictionary.txt is a valid url because it's in the same folder as the .js file and the html file. Everything about this code works except returning te value of `ajaxResponse`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped me answer this question! All the answers given contained usefull relevant information to help answer the question, however, since no one response contained all the understanding I needed to resolve my problem I am posting the answer.

The solution is as follows:

1. I needed to use a [callback function](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/).
2. The callback function should only execute after the XHR request had been completed.

   -This is especially important and relevant to the fact that we are using asynchronous AJAX.
3. I needed to make sure that `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist` was set as equal to the appropriate value `ajaxResponse`, and not to `ALAMI.XHR.Get()`.

The code I came up with is as follows.

```
ALAMI.XHR.Get = function(URL, callback){ //callback argument was added
  "use strict";
  var ajaxRequest = ALAMI.XHR();
  var ajaxResponse;

  ajaxRequest.open("GET", URL, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
      ajaxResponse = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n");
      var extensionLocation = URL.lastIndexOf('.');
      console.log(URL.substr(extensionLocation) + " file, " + ajaxResponse.length + " lines");
      if(callback){
        callback(ajaxResponse); //callback is called after URL is parsed into an Array
      }
    }
  }
}

ALAMI.Hangman = ALAMI.Hangman || {};
ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist;

ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt', function(aR){ //callback function is specified
  ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist = aR;                    //assigning the Wordlist property now works!
  console.log('Wordlist Retrieved');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**edited based on comment**]

If you want to populate `ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist` from the result of the XHR request, you should do that in the callback of that request

```
ALAMI.Hangman = ALAMI.Hangman || {};

//change ALAMI.XHR.Get = function(URL) to
//       ALAMI.XHR.Get = function(URL,listID)

ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt','WordList');
ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary2.txt','WordList2');
ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary3.txt','WordList3');

// [...]
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
      ajaxResponse = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n");
      var extensionLocation = URL.lastIndexOf('.');
      ALAMI.Hangman[listID]  = ajaxResponse; // <===
      // [...]
      // do stuff with the populated ALAMI.Hangman[listID]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that I'm trying to make my ajax function a universal method that  can use an infinite number of times.
for example: `Wordlist1 = ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt')`
`Wordlist2 = ALAMI.XHR.Get('dictionary2.txt')` I have already done what you suggested but it doesn't satisfy my end goal.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't really solve my problem in the end. What happens when I want to start using `ALAMI.Hangman[WordList]` or `ALAMI.Hangman.WordList` in a bazillion other functions throughout my code? It keeps showing up as undefined when I do what you have mentioned?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on XMLHttpRequest usage, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest. Hint: it's the callback stupid ... Alternatively you can try to find someone to do the coding for you

Comment: Don't call me stupid, I've been studying as much as I can. Your code was just fine, the only problem is that when I was testing the value of `ALAMI.Hangman.WordList` I was using `console.log(ALAMI.Hangman.WordList[0])` in the global 'arena' and the only reason it didn't work was because it was being called before the callback function was called. So I appreciate your help, but you could have just explained that the AJAX function hadn't finished yet.  Anyway, thanks for trying to help, I ended up doing something slightly different than what you suggested but with the same end result.

Comment: I don't call *you* stupid. It's a paraphrase: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It's_the_economy,_stupid.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a WordList object and then pass it around the rest of your program without neccessarily invoking the ajax request until the WordList is accessed?

You are running into problems because without using callbacks the rest of your code is trying to evaluate WordList before the AJAX request is fulfilled, in fact even if the resquest has been filled, the browser is waiting for your current 'loop' of code to finish before it executes the readystatechange callback to populate your list.  You can use a sync AJAX call, or I would probably rewrite your XHR function the following way:

```
function wordlist(url,withwords) {
    var xhr = // create your xhr object;
    xhr.onload = function (data) {
        withwords(parsetolist(data));
    }
    xhr.send()
}

wordlist('dict1.txt', function(words) {
    // pass words around to other functions
    filterwords(words);
    randomizewords(words);
    // or use it here
    console.log(words[2]);
}
```

If you truly want to set the word list to a global so other programs can use it outside
of the local code then you'll have to change wordlist to a function that takes a callback on every use...  not as pretty. at least that way you can evaluate more lazily

```
function wordlist2(url) {
    var evaluated = false;
    var response = function (index, withword) {
        if ( evaluated ) { withword(evaluated[index]); }
        else {
            wordlist(url, function(words) {
                 evaluated = words;
                 withword(words[index]);
            })
        }
    }
    return response;
}
ALAMI.WORDLIST = wordlist2('dict1.txt');
ALAMI.WORDLIST(2,function (word) { console.log(word); });
```

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right. I'm glad you mentioned that because no one else did, fortunately I already discovered that and revamped my solution. Here is the jsfiddle of my updated code if you want to tell me what you think? http://jsfiddle.net/d5ANd/10/
Also, to be clear I want the Wordlist to load when the page loads and then just have it accessible as an Array throughout the rest of the users visit to the page (game-play).

Comment: i expanded a little more, before I saw your comment, I'll check out the jsfiddle.

Comment: that looks fine, though I suggest if you want to try and catch 'legacy' browser support for AJAX just use a library like jquery.  Another useful pattern you might use, is that you can use event passing and attach a bunch of listeners to wordlist, so that when the wordlist gets filled they all get called... this might or might not lead to cleaner code depending on how many different points wordlist is accessed from, and how independent those are.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing:  if you're starting out in JS I'd say learn JS well enough to read it, but if you can, try out something like CoffeeScript http://coffeescript.org/, which IMO has much better syntax and enforces some good practices, or if callbacks have you down I've been really impressed with this: http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/

Comment: Yeah, I know about jquery, honestly though I guess I'm trying to 'reinvent the wheel'. Since I'm learning JavaScript I decided I want to eventually learn just about every (necessary) trick in the book, so that in the future (although I will be using jquery, etc) my knowledge and skills wont be completely dependent on libraries.  As far as your other comment goes, I will for sure be using event liseners, but the wordlist will not be accessed directly by the user at all. Thanks for your help and comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

there's a problem in how you're using the XMLHttpRequest() object. Because you've specified `true` in `ajaxRequest.open("GET", URL, true);` you are actually asking that the request be completed in asynchronous thread so that the main thread doesn't get blocked. This is good design for HTML applications but it requires you to understand better on how to handle the results better, take the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ALAMI Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function doit(URL) {
  console.log('mainthread - doit begin');
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", URL, true);
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
      console.log('asyncthread - readystatechange begin');
      var ajaxResponse = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("\n");
      var extensionLocation = URL.lastIndexOf('.');
      console.log('asyncthread - readystatechange end');
    }
  }
  console.log('mainthread - ajaxRequest.send');
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
  console.log('manthread - doit end');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="doit" onclick="doit('http://localhost/fulldictionary.txt')"/>
</body>
```

Note the locations where I've marked `console.log` and which are in the *mainthread* and which are in the *asyncthread*. If you were to run the script, you should see the following text appear in the console:

```
LOG: mainthread - doit begin 
LOG: mainthread - ajaxRequest.send 
LOG: manthread - doit end 
LOG: asyncthread - readystatechange begin 
LOG: asyncthread - readystatechange end
```

The way how you've written your script, you have assumed that the results occur synchronously, i.e.

```
LOG: mainthread - doit begin 
LOG: mainthread - ajaxRequest.send 
LOG: asyncthread - readystatechange begin 
LOG: asyncthread - readystatechange end 
LOG: manthread - doit end
```

which is why your script doesn't work. The correct design is to continue working with the asynchthread but use it to "post back" records it found back to your ALAMI object. So, you cannot use the following line of code:

```
ALAMI.Hangman.Wordlist = ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt');
```

Because when the mainthread completes, the wordlist is still unknown, instead, you have to rewrite it as this:

```
ALAMI.XHR.Get('fulldictionary.txt');
```

And within the implementation of your asyncthread you have to make it populate your Wordlist.

i.e. there's some redesign required.

Comment: Yes, I think you explained it better than anyone, however, I did already do all the redesigning if you'd like to take a look and comment on my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5ANd/10/
Let me know if you think tha sufficiently resolves the problem.

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob that looks better.